# The letters A B C D E are arranged randomly in a line. In how many arrangements is the letter A in front of D?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The letters A B C D E are arranged randomly in a line. In how many arrangements is the letter A in front of D?

Any idea how I can do this? I was thinking of drawing out all possible cases, but is there a faster way that can be used to generalize to a large number of unique items?

Right now I have :

A L L L  D = 3!

L A L L D = $^3C_2 \cdot 2$

L L A L D = $^3C_2 \cdot 2$

L L L A D = 3!

So total there are 24 possible arrangements. Am I on the right track?

Comment: How about the cases $ALDLL$? Note that either $A$ is in front of $D$ or $D$ is in front of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There'll be exactly half of total permutations in which A is before D and half in which A is after D.

Hence desired is $$ \dfrac{5!}{2}=60$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel silly to have not considered that.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose $3$ places out of $5$ and place $B, C, E$ in those in $3!$ ways. Order of $A, D$ is fixed.

So total number of desired ways = ${5 \choose 3} \times 3! = 60$